# Show notification on a website on only the first visit

Tags: vue.js, notifications, nuxt.js

When I update my website I would like the users to get a notification, via a bar on the top of the page, stating what the update has been. How do I make it so that when the user goes back to the website that same notification doesn't pop up every time, only the first time?

I'm using Nuxt, or Vue.js. I was trying to get vue-toast to do this but I'm not sure how, but I'll use anything that works. I'm guessing I could use local storage somehow, but I would have more notifications that would need to show about once a week or so.

Comment: If you save the date a visitor arrives in local storage you can check every visitor to see if they have previously visited.  Once you know the date of your latest visit you can compare that to any changes you've made and toast accordingly.

Comment: are the notifications saved in a db? and are the users saved in a db?

Comment: Use localStorage if you only need this information on client side, otherwise use a cookie if this information must be processed by the back end.